Drawing outside container boundary in jetpack compose
I need to make a container with rounded corners , that has a circle fitted so that half of it is outside the container and half of it is inside. I have achieved a rectangle with no rounded corners with the code below

 Box(modifier = Modifier
    .fillMaxWidth()
    .height(100.dp)
    .padding(top = 20.dp)
    
    .background(ColorScheme.Quaternary.toColor().first)
    ) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .layout { measurable, constraints ->
                // Measure the child
                val placeable = measurable.measure(constraints)

                // Set the width and height of the layout as measured
                layout(placeable.width, placeable.height) {
                    // Place the child such that half of it is outside the top boundary
                    placeable.place(0, -25.dp.roundToPx())  // Moves the circle up by 25dp
                }
            }
            .size(50.dp)
            .clip(CircleShape)
            .background(Color.Red)

    )
}

When i attempt to round the container , the red circle also gets clipped

This is the code where I have called clip on the modifier (note I have also tried calling clip at different positions in the modifier change , but the effect is the same)
Box(modifier = Modifier
    .fillMaxWidth()
    .height(100.dp)
    .padding(top = 20.dp)
    .clip(RoundedCornerShape(10.dp))
    .background(ColorScheme.Quaternary.toColor().first)
    ) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .layout { measurable, constraints ->
                // Measure the child
                val placeable = measurable.measure(constraints)

                // Set the width and height of the layout as measured
                layout(placeable.width, placeable.height) {
                    // Place the child such that half of it is outside the top boundary
                    placeable.place(0, -25.dp.roundToPx())  // Moves the circle up by 25dp
                }
            }
            .size(50.dp)
            .clip(CircleShape)
            .background(Color.Red)

    )
}

any ideas folks ?

In Jetpack Compose none of the Composables or drawings inside DrawScope via Modifier.drawWBehind/WithContent/WİthCache are not clipped unless parent calls Modifier.clip(), Modifier.graphicsLayer{clip = true} directly or under the hood.
You can remove Modifier.clip(RoundedCornerShape(10.dp)) from parent composable and change background with
Modifier.background(ColorScheme.Quaternary.toColor().first, RoundedCornerShape(10.dp))

You can also Modifier.drawBehind to draw a rounded rectangle and circle behind your composable as
Box(modifier = Modifier
    .fillMaxWidth()
    .height(100.dp)
    .padding(top = 20.dp)
    .drawBehind {
        drawRoundRect(
            color = Color.Gray,
            cornerRadius = CornerRadius(10.dp.toPx(), 10.dp.toPx())
        )
        drawCircle(
            color = Color.Red,
            radius =  25.dp.toPx(),
            center = Offset(25.dp.toPx(), 0f)
        )
    }
)

